# Coefficient of $x^n$ in Legendre series expansion

Tags: power-series, special-functions, approximation, legendre-polynomials, chebyshev-polynomials

Suppose we are approximating a function $f$ with a Legendre series of order $N$, namely
$$
f(x) \approx \sum_{n=0}^N c_n P_n(x) \equiv f_N(x)
$$
where $P_n(x)$ is the $n^{th}$ Legendre polynomial and
$$
c_n = \int_{-1}^1 dx f(x) P_n(x) .
$$
Now, the above approximation can be rewritten as
$$
f_N(x) = \sum_{n=0}^N c'_n x^n .
$$
I would like to know if there is a closed equation to relate the coefficients $\{c'_n\}_{n=0}^N$ in terms of the $\{c_n\}_{n=0}^N$.

In [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1822804/legendre-polynomial-coefficients) question I found the (undocumented) relation
$$
P_n(x) = \frac{1}{2^n} \sum_{k=0}^{\left[ \frac{n}{2} \right]} (-1)^k \frac{(2n-2k)!}{k!(n-k)!(n-2k)!} x^{n-2k}
$$
which would then make
$$
c'_n = \frac{1}{2^n} \sum_{k=0}^{\left[ \frac{n}{2} \right]} (-1)^k \frac{(2n-2k)!}{k!(n-k)!(n-2k)!} c_{n-2k}
$$
at least for even $n$.

I was also wondering whether the same request could be answered for Chebyshev (or other orthogonal) polynomials replacing Legendre polynomials in the above question.